# C program: Error reading and printing a particular column from a text file

Tags: c, file

I want to print column 6 from a text file "1PGB.pdb" into an output file "out". Following is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* For exit() function*/
#define ROW 500
#define COL 12
int main()
{
int n6, garbage;
FILE *fp;
FILE *op = fopen("out", "w");
int score[ROW][COL];
int row, col, item, i, j;
if ((fp=fopen("1PGB.pdb","r"))==NULL)
{
        printf("Error! opening file");
        exit(1);         /* Program exits if file pointer returns NULL. */
}
for(row=0; row<ROW; row++)
{
col=5;


fscanf(fp, "%d", &score[row][col]);
fprintf(op, "%d", score[row][col]);

fclose(fp);
    fclose(op);
 }
 return 0;
 }
```

It gives the following error.

Error in `./Code1': double free or corruption (out): 0x0000000000cde250 ***
Aborted (core dumped)

The first few lines of 1PGB.pdb file are:

```
ATOM      1  N   MET A   1      12.969  18.506  30.954  1.00 15.93           N  
ATOM      2  CA  MET A   1      13.935  18.529  29.843  1.00 17.40           C  
ATOM      3  C   MET A   1      13.138  18.692  28.517  1.00 14.65           C  
ATOM      4  O   MET A   1      12.007  18.222  28.397  1.00 13.04           O  
ATOM      5  CB  MET A   1      14.733  17.216  29.882  1.00 20.72           C  
ATOM      6  CG  MET A   1      15.742  16.983  28.738  1.00 23.81           C  
ATOM      7  SD  MET A   1      17.378  17.025  29.359  1.00 28.11           S  
ATOM      8  CE  MET A   1      17.166  16.055  30.819  1.00 27.51           C  
ATOM      9  N   THR A   2      13.719  19.413  27.573  1.00 12.63           N  
ATOM     10  CA  THR A   2      13.088  19.661  26.283  1.00 12.68           C  
ATOM     11  C   THR A   2      13.561  18.631  25.300  1.00 12.02           C  
ATOM     12  O   THR A   2      14.763  18.432  25.121  1.00 13.07           O  
ATOM     13  CB  THR A   2      13.527  20.980  25.667  1.00 14.62           C
```

Comment: Can you supply (the first few lines of) `1PGB.pdb`? Is it [this one](http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/files/1PGB.pdb)?

Comment: No, I have removed the headers.

Comment: You never told us what the input was, so how are we meant to explain your output?

Comment: I've edited the question.

Comment: You've told `fscanf` to expect integers, but the input starts with non-numeric fields.

Comment: For each row in the file, you `fclose`...  Indenting your code correctly might help you find problems like this.

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm not using the header lines, in that case, the input i.e. column 6, has integer constants.

Comment: It is not quite clear which part of the code is supposed to be responsible for reading column 6 and leaving out all other columns.

Comment: Try `fscanf(fp, "%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%d%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s". &x);` where `x` is of type `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a good, simple approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char line[1000];
    int n6;
    FILE *fp = fopen("1PGB.pdb", "r");
    FILE *op = fopen("out", "w");

    if (fp == NULL || op == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file.");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != 0)
    {
        /* Use "%*s" to skip a word when using scanf. */
        sscanf(line, "%*s %*s %*s %*s %*s %d", &n6);
        fprintf(op, "%d\n", n6);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Mauris It'll be great help if you tell me how to store these values in an array so that I can avoid keeping an extra file for that.

Comment: Define a `struct` representing the data in one row of your file. Then declare an array (say `pdb_data`) of "enough" such structs, and pass arguments like `&(pdb_data[i].n6)` to `scanf` to make it fill up the `i`'th struct in your array. (Start at `i = 0` and put `i++` after the `scanf` line.)