# C programming: How to extract a particular column from an input file and store in an array

Tags: c, arrays, file

I want to store the integer values from column 6 of an input file "out" in an array so that I can do further operations on it.

Following is the code I have written to put values from an input text file to an array but it does not specify values from column 6:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
  {
    int len = 0;
    char line[1000];
    char line2[1000];
    char *pch;
    char c[6] = "ATOM ";
    FILE *fp = fopen("1PGB.pdb", "r");
    FILE *op = fopen("out", "w");
    if(fp == NULL || op == NULL)
      {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file.");
        exit(1);
     }
   else 
     {
       while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != 0)
        {
         if((pch = strstr (line, c))!= 0)
         fprintf(op, "%s\n", line);
        }
    }
 fclose(fp);
 fclose(op);
 FILE *ip = fopen("out", "r");
 int numberArray[500];
 int i;

 for (i = 0; i < 500; i++)
  {
    fscanf(ip, "%1d", &numberArray[i]);
  }

for (i = 0; i < 500; i++)
{
    printf("Number is: %d\n\n", numberArray[i]);
}

 fclose(ip);
}
```

Following is my input file:

```
ATOM      1  N   MET A   1      12.969  18.506  30.954  1.00 15.93           N  

ATOM      2  CA  MET A   1      13.935  18.529  29.843  1.00 17.40           C  

ATOM      3  C   MET A   1      13.138  18.692  28.517  1.00 14.65           C  

ATOM      4  O   MET A   1      12.007  18.222  28.397  1.00 13.04           O  

ATOM      5  CB  MET A   1      14.733  17.216  29.882  1.00 20.72           C  

ATOM      6  CG  MET A   1      15.742  16.983  28.738  1.00 23.81           C  

ATOM      7  SD  MET A   1      17.378  17.025  29.359  1.00 28.11           S  

ATOM      8  CE  MET A   1      17.166  16.055  30.819  1.00 27.51           C  

ATOM      9  N   THR A   2      13.719  19.413  27.573  1.00 12.63           N  

ATOM     10  CA  THR A   2      13.088  19.661  26.283  1.00 12.68           C  

ATOM     11  C   THR A   2      13.561  18.631  25.300  1.00 12.02           C  

ATOM     12  O   THR A   2      14.763  18.432  25.121  1.00 13.07           O  

ATOM     13  CB  THR A   2      13.527  20.980  25.667  1.00 14.62           C  

ATOM     14  OG1 THR A   2      13.307  22.020  26.627  1.00 15.31           O  

ATOM     15  CG2 THR A   2      12.704  21.284  24.409  1.00 14.47           C  

ATOM     16  N   TYR A   3      12.574  18.048  24.642  1.00 11.17           N
```

My question is what changes do I need to make in this code to extract only column 6 to put it into an array. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33809497/c-program-error-reading-and-printing-a-particular-column-from-a-text-file

Answer (score -1):

starting from your previous post commented by @BLUEPIXY which is [C program: Error reading and printing a particular column from a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33809497/c-program-error-reading-and-printing-a-particular-column-from-a-text-file)

at the beginning

```
op=fopen("out.bin","wb");//open a new binary file in write mode
```

then

```
//fprintf(op, "%d\n", n6); remove this
fwrite(&n6,sizeof(n6),1,op);// replace it by this
```

at the end

```
fclose(op); // close the output file
op=fopen("out.bin","rb");//reopen it in read mode
fsseek(op,0,SEEK_END);
int len=ftell(op); // get file size in bytes
fsseek(op,0,SEEK_SET);//rewind to 0;

int *arr=malloc(len);//WARNING: error checking omitted
fread(arr,len,1,op); //load all content in array
fclose(fp);

len/=sizeof(int); //len of array 
for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    printf("%d",arr[i]); //print content

//when done free memory
free(arr);
```

Answer (score -1):

this is the full code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>


int *loadBin(char *f,int *len){
    int n=0;
    int *arr=NULL;
    *len=0;
    FILE *op=fopen(f,"rb");

    if(op){
        fseek(op,0,SEEK_END);
        n=ftell(op);
        if(n>0){
            *len=(n)/sizeof(int);
            fseek(op,0,SEEK_SET);
            arr=malloc(n);
            fread(arr,1,n,op);
        }
    }
    if(errno)
        perror("LoadBin()");
    return arr;
}

/*____________________________________________________________
*/
int main()
{
    char line[1000];
    int n6;
    FILE *fp = fopen("1PGB.pdb", "r");
    FILE *op = fopen("out", "wb"); // always in binary mode ("wb"|"rb")
    char buff[50];
    if (fp == NULL || op == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file.");
        exit(1);
    }

    //SAVE
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != 0)
    {
        /* Use "%*s" to skip a word when using scanf. */
        //sscanf(line, "%*s %*s %*s %*s %*s %d", &n6);
        sscanf(line, "%s %*s %*s %*s %*s %d",buff, &n6);
        //            ^                   ^____________ n6
        //            ^_________________________________buff

        if(!strstr(buff,"END")) //skip last line
            fwrite(&n6, sizeof(n6),1, op);
    }
    fclose(op);
    fclose(fp);

    // READ
    int *arr,len;
    arr=loadBin("out",&len);
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
        printf("%d\n",arr[i]);
    free(arr);

    return 0;
}
```